# sticky footer and fixed header

Tags: html, css

I have tried couples of solution on google for sticky footer. My current testing one works fine but the footer will not push down if content is overflow a page.

Questions:
1. footer will not push down if content is overflowed. How can I make it to push down when there is more content?

2. As screen re-size to smaller, the header height does not fixed, thus the nav is overlapping with the header. How should I adjust my header so that even with a smaller screen the header will stay the same as full screen mode?

css:

```
/* basic set up*/
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #CCCC52;
    width: 100%;
    height: 6%;
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
/* header */
    .header p, .header ul, .header ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        *display: inline;
        zoom: 1;
    }
    .header p, .header ul {
        margin: 0.5% 0 0 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 50%;
    }
        .header p {
            margin-left: 2%;
            width: 48%; 
        }
        .header ul {
            text-align: right;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        .header ul li {
            margin: 0 5%;
            padding: 1.5% 2%;
            background-color: #e44c65;
        }
```

Here is what I got so far. Fiddle **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zaaqwkq2/)**

P.S. ** Sorry that I forgot to mention but I actually have to support I.E. 7 as well. I know...its stupid...

P.S. I have tried to mess with the recommended solution but its either header not fixed or I.E. 7 not supported(:after not support in I.E. 7)

Comment: Well for one, you should not rely so heavily on position absolute. You're going to run into issues like this every step of the way, if you do. **[Here's a sticky footer method that I'd recommend](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)** I usually use almost identical method myself. As far as fixed header goes, you should be fine just setting `#header { position: fixed; }`

Comment: Wrap your `footer` inside `wrapper`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Questions: 1

Just put the `<div class="footer">` into the `<div class="wrapper">`

> Questions: 2

You use % at your `margin` and `padding`. e.g. `margin: 0.5% 0 0 0;`
And `height: 6%;` for the `.header`. This can cause some problems on window resize.

EDIT:

Maybe you want to use some html5?

There are the `<header>` and `<footer>` tags. So you don´t have to use a div for everything.

Watch out for IE8 and below. You need some fix to use html5 tags there.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="content">
   All content goes in here
 <\div>

 .content{
   Min-height:100%;
 }
```

Your first question solution